# Discord.py replace symbols in user nicknames

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I want to reset Usernames like "几乇尺ㄒㄖ乂" with the normal alphabetic letters, but I don't know-how. I don't think it's possible to replace all cryptic(?) letters correctly with the normal alphabetic letters, so I want to detect such an awkward letter and want to rename the username to "Change your nickname!".

I tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
async def user():
      if '几' in member.display_name:
         await member.edit(nick='Name ändern!')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a list of wanted letters. Then you can check the letters of the member's display name with this list.

```py
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', '1', '2', '3']
async def user():
    [await member.edit(nick='Change your name!') for letter in member.display_name if letter not in letters]
```

So with this code, it'll iterate through `member.display_name` then check if one of the letters is not in the `letters` list. You just have to expand the `letters` list.

Comment: Thank you i will try that out! Is it possible to allow all emojis without adding all emojis?

Comment: Probably yes, you should check the [`emoji`](https://pypi.org/project/emoji/) library for the discord emojis and for custom emojis, I think you should look [`discord.Emoji`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Emoji).

Comment: How can i add all discord emojis to the "letters" ?

Comment: You don't have to add all the emojis. If you search a little bit about `emoji` library, you can see it has a function called `emoji_count(string)`. So you can check member's nickname with it. For example `if emoji.emoji_count(member.display_name) > 0:`.